# whitelisting IP in NGINX stream directive

Tags: nginx

I have the following NGINX config file:

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
}

stream {

    upstream rancher_servers_http {
        least_conn;
        server <IP_NODE_1>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <IP_NODE_2>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <IP_NODE_3>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }

    server {
        listen     80;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;
    }

    upstream rancher_servers_https {
        least_conn;
        <IP_NODE_1>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        <IP_NODE_2>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        <IP_NODE_3>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }

    server {
        listen     443;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;
    }
}
```

And I would like to whitelist certain IPs for the subdomain `*.dev.mydomain.com`.

I tried to add this to the server block:

```
if ($host ~ *.dev.mydomain.com) {
    allow: <ip1>,<ip2>
    deny: all;
}
```

But I have the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here

I then tried to add a `map`. Under the server block I also have a `directive not allowed here` but I can add the map inside the stream block.

When I add the map on the stream block as follow:

```
map $hostname $deny_ips {
    default all;
    ~*.dev.mydomain.com all;
}
```

I can't use the `deny_ips` variable in server block, I get a

> [emerg] invalid parameter "deny_ips" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35

Note also that I can't map `$host` but I can only map `$hostname` or I got a

> nginx: [emerg] unknown "host" variable

Can someone please help me to whitelist certain ips based on the subdomain ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just noticed the **stream** part; what are you trying to load-balance? If it's just HTTP/S traffic you should be able to use `http` instead of `stream`.

Comment: I'm loadbalancing nodes on a kubernetes cluster (built with rancher rke). I'm not 100% sure but I think I should use a TCP load-balancing in that case, as requests on pods might be on a different protocol than http. It's not actually the case but it might be.

Comment: The thing is that for a simple TCP connection there's no `"server_name"` variable that nginx can interpret and act upon. But if you're using nginx to expose services from your kubernetes cluster I'm guessing you will only expose HTTP/S services so you can give the solution below a try.

Comment: I think the pods themselves will communicate with one another directly (rather than via nginx) so you should be OK there (at least that's how it is on docker swarm which I used).

Comment: Ok I could give it a try but would I be able to keep the SSL cert management on the kubernetes cluster as it is ? I'm new to nginx and I often see SSL management on the nginx part when it's about http. That was also one of the reason why I preffered tcp load balancing.

Comment: The requirement is a bit complex for nginx and its ACL system but I think `haproxy` can handle it. Can you give it a try? I'm really curious as I haven't used it so far.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a solution with `nginx` but did not get far; I used an **http** block for regular HTTP traffic (this parts works OK) and a **stream** block for SSL (see second part of the answer for details).

However, I think [haproxy](https://www.haproxy.com/) can be used here as it seems to be more flexible when configuring ACLs.

## haproxy solution

```
global
    maxconn     20000
    log         127.0.0.1 local0
    user        haproxy
    chroot      /usr/share/haproxy
    pidfile     /run/haproxy.pid
    daemon

defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s

frontend ssl
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  acl network_allowed src 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.3/32  <-- EDIT IPs
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  acl dev_domain req_ssl_sni -m end .dev.mydomain.com  <-- EDIT domain
  tcp-request content reject if !network_allowed dev_domain
  use_backend rancher_servers_https

backend rancher_servers_https
  balance leastconn
  mode tcp
  server node1 1.2.3.4:443 fall 3 rise 2  <-- EDIT IP
  server node2 2.3.4.5:443 fall 3 rise 2  <-- EDIT IP
  server node3 3.4.5.6:443 fall 3 rise 2  <-- EDIT IP
```

I marked the place where you would need to edit the config and you'll probably need to tweak the `global` section as well (depending on your distro).
The above is for the SSL part; the non-encrypted part should be similar but without the SNI/SSL parts.
Please note I haven't tried this and I have not used haproxy before but I think it will set you on the right path.

## nginx solution - incomplete

I used map `$ssl_preread_server_name` for getting the domain name via **SNI** and a `geo` block for matching non-allowed IPs.

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $dev_upstream {
    hostnames;
    *.dev.mydomain.com  1;
    default     0;
}

geo $not_dev_whitelist {
    default         1;
    192.168.1.0/24  0;
    2001:0db8::/32  0;
}
```

However because `if` is not allowed in the stream block I can't do:

```
server {
    listen     443;
    if ($dev_upstream) {
        set $dev "1";
    }
    if ($not_dev_whitelist) {
        set $dev "${dev}1";
    }
    if ($dev = "11") {
        return "blocked";
    }
    proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First Nginx does not allow nested if statements. You need to use map functionality to achieve your goal.

Second you are wrong with map implement

```
map "$http_referer:$arg_78up" $refernotok {
    default 1;
    ~ mywebsite.com.*:.*$ 0;
    ~ ^.+:.+$ 0;
}

if ($refernotok = "1") {
    return 404;
}
```

you should use $http_referer for your map .

First part is regular expression. ^ means start of string, .+ means one or more characters, : is a delimiter character, and then again we match one or more characters with .+, and finally we require the string ending with $. 0 is the value $refernotok variable gets when the regular expression matches.

Comment: How is HTTP referer relevant in this case? It's a `stream` balancer, not an HTTP balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two server blocks.

```
    server {
        listen       80  default_server;
        server_name  _;

        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  *.dev.mydomain.com;

        allow <ip1>;
        allow <ip2>;
        deny all;

        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;
    }

.. same for the server on :443
```

Also. if you're using nginx-ingress you can whitelist IPs with annotations. See [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range). I find it easier to manage than manually configuing nginx.